# eslint react to format curly braces

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettify

I can't find any react eslint rule to prettify the content between the curly braces

```js
<div>
   {
              items.map(i => (<div>{i}</div>))
           }
</div>
```

It should look like this

```js
<div>
  {
      items.map(i => (<div>{i}</div>))
  }
</div>
```

Comment: That seems like an indentation issue, rather than anything to do with the braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not specific to React, the ESLint indent rule (https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/indent) also handles indentation in JSX.

It's not unfortunately not in eslint:recommended, so you need to enable it yourself in your configuration like so:

```json
// .eslintrc.json
{
  // ... rest of your configuration
  "rules": {
    "indent": ["error"] // or "warn" if you prefer
  }
}
```

The default is 4-space indentation, but you can also set it to use 2 spaces `["error", 2]` or tabs `["error", "tab"]`.

When it comes to formatting rather than actual code errors, I would recommend using Prettier or another tool specifically made for formatting, instead of ESLint. See this article by the ESLint team (https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting/formatting)

> Stylistic rules are frozen - we won’t be adding any more options to stylistic rules. We’ve learned that there’s no way to satisfy everyone’s personal preferences, and most of the rules already have a lot of difficult-to-understand options. Stylistic rules are those related to spacing, conventions, and generally anything that does not highlight an error or a better way to do something. Update 2021-01-29: We clarified in the README that we will still support newly-added ECMAScript features.

Comment: Thx, I also need to disable `@typescript-eslint/indent` and it's working.